# Top collaborator MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset where all authors associated with book are listed like below

```
| Book ID | Author |
|---------|--------|
| 1       | A      |
| 1       | B      |
| 1       | C      |
| 2       | A      |
| 2       | X      |
| 3       | P      |
| 3       | C      |
| 4       | Q      |
| 4       | B      |
```

And I want to find out which author is top collaborator, means worked with different authors. Like in above case

A has worked with B, C, X

```
B -> A, C, Q
C -> A, B, P
P -> C
X -> A
Q -> B
```

I tried few combinations of group concat but desired results are not coming

Comment: may be you forgot second table or tell what is the realtion between A and B,C and X ?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting project, do let us know if you have a question! If you do have a question, then pls include what you have tried to achieve the expected outcome and pls also specify the expected outcome along with what you have received when you run your own query.

Comment: @krishnpatel the bookid field provides the relationship you are looking for.

Comment: @Shadow Let me update question with whatever I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use self-join to get the collaborators.  Then you can use `count(distinct)` to count them:

```
select ba.author, count(distinct ba2.author) as num_collaborators,
       group_concat(distinct ba2.author0 as collaborators
from book_authors ba join
     book_authors ba2
     on ba.book_id = ba2.book_id and ba.author <> ba2.author
group by ba.author
order by num_collaborators desc;
```

Comment: In the sample above 3 authors have the same number of collaborators, so all of them are top ones. Your query returns only one of them. An unclear "question" with no demonstrated own question -> are you sure that it needs answering?

Comment: @Shadow . . . Actually, the OP suggests that s/he wants all the collaborators, so I modified the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks its working. This is what I was expecting

Comment: @Shadow - I was updating question with whatever I have tried and if you could have given normal hint that in which direct should I explore, i would have really appreciated that. I know maintaining quality questions on stack community is one of your motive, but I was unable to find any question on stack discussing about this concept. ***tldr; there are polite words available to convey your message***

Comment: @user199354 your question still does not include what you have tried because there is still no code in your "question" and there is still no question there. Only a description of your requirements. P.s. I did not use any impolite words.